# How can I convert a Lisp expression to a LaTeX math expression?

Tags: latex, math

How can I convert a lisp
expression to LaTeX math expression.

From simple things like `(- 3 2 1)` which should be converted to `3 - 2 - 1`, to relatively complex things like: `(* 1 2 (/ 2 3))` ⇒ `1 \times 2 \times \frac{2}{3}`, or `(somefunc 1 2)` ⇒ `somefunc(1,2)`, and so on.

Even being able to use some variables instead of numbers and convert them would be nice.

I type Lisp expressions in Emacs a lot, because I can just evaluate that there and get the output. That means I don't have to actually run a calculator or a terminal elsewhere. But I'd like to put valid LaTeX math expressions into the reports, and instead of typing again.

Is there any package that can help with that, or do I have to write the Elisp with a parser myself?

I found https://alejandrogallo.github.io/listex/ which seems to be for writing LaTeX in Lisp. I do not want to write LaTeX in Lisp. I want to convert already written valid Lisp expressions to LaTeX math expressions.

---

EDIT:
Based on the accepted answer I ended up making a whole minor mode centering around this functionality.

Here's the link: https://github.com/Atreyagaurav/litex-mode

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Is your question about LaTeX expressions in general or just LaTeX math expressions. Please clarify the question for this.

Comment: It's about latex math expressions. Also about the elisp tag info, the solution to this depends on parsing elisp expressions, so I considered it specific to elisp, I hope that tag is fine.

Comment: No, tag `elisp` is not about using Elisp to do something. It's about Elisp as a particular Lisp dialect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a toy function:

```lisp
(defvar lisp2latex-need-parens nil)
(defun lisp2latex (form)
  (pcase form
    (`(+ . ,args)
     (let ((ret (let ((lisp2latex-need-parens nil))
                  (mapconcat #'lisp2latex args " + "))))
       (if lisp2latex-need-parens
           (concat "(" ret ")")
         ret)))
    (`(- ,a1 . ,args)
     (let ((ret
            (if args
                (format "%s - %s" (lisp2latex a1)
                        (let ((lisp2latex-need-parens t))
                          (mapconcat #'lisp2latex args " - ")))
              (format "- %s" (lisp2latex a1)))))
       (if lisp2latex-need-parens
           (concat "(" ret ")")
         ret)))
    (`(* . ,args)
     (let ((lisp2latex-need-parens t))
       (mapconcat #'lisp2latex args " \\times ")))
    (`(/ ,a1 . ,args)
     (if args
         (format "\\frac{%s}{%s}" (lisp2latex a1)
                 (lisp2latex (cons '* args)))
       (format "\\frac1{%s}" (lisp2latex a1))))
    (`(,func . ,args)
     (format "%s(%s)" func (mapconcat #'lisp2latex args ",")))
    (_ (prin1-to-string form))))

(lisp2latex '(* (/ (log 4 64)) (/ 3 (+ 4 6) 8)))
"\\frac1{log(4,64)} \\times \\frac{3}{(4 + 6) \\times 8}"
```

It probably adds too many parens...

Comment: That's like super fast, I can't believe how fast you did it, also it seems to work if I add other functions in the pcase, like `(\`(setq . ,args) (mapconcat #'lisp2latex args " = "))`.

Comment: I think your `setq` clause is _wrong_ for more than 1 assignment.

Comment: I was also thinking that, but for now I just wanted to see if I could add any functions there.
If it works then, can you modify the default expression to print `function(arg1,arg2, ...)` format instead of `(function arg1 arg2 ...)` format?

Comment: I tried `(_ (format "%s%s" (car form) (cdr form)))` for the last one, and it does convert `(sin 1)` to `sin(1)` form, but again it doesn't work for multiple arguments. I tried `(mapconcat #'lisp2latex (list (cdr form)) ", ")` for second `%s` but it didn't work at all.

Comment: what's wrong with my current version?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize you made an edit, I was just trying to make that in my local copy and added that comment in the tab that wasn't refreshed since I added the comment above that one. Your version does indeed work. I think I can now make add more functions, it's clear now. Thank you.

Comment: By adding `let ((lisp2latex-need-parens t))` in the evaluation for `-` operator were you perhaps trying to do `(lisp2latex (cons '+ args))` for everything after the first argument? Because currently changing t to nil doesn't change anything.